# I can't install w3af and run w3af_console

Tags: software-installation

Error running w3af_console:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./w3af_console", line 12, in <module>
    from w3af.core.controllers.dependency_check.dependency_check import dependency_check
  File "/home/queez/w3af/w3af/core/controllers/dependency_check/dependency_check.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pip
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 32, in vendored
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 118, in <module>
    SSL_ST_INIT = _lib.SSL_ST_INIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSL_ST_INIT'
```

Comment: OK so four reviewers weren't aware that w3af-console is in the Ubuntu repositories and so they started downvoting the question and railroading it closed. However now that this information is in the public domain, this question still being downvoted. Back off and close a snake oil question instead.

Answer (score 2):

w3af-console is in the default Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04. The reason why you got these errors is that you installed a w3af-console package from somewhere else instead of installing the w3af-console package from the default Ubuntu repositories. So uninstall the existing w3af-console package and then reinstall it properly using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install w3af-console
```